# virtualbox copy from Linux guest to non-Linux host using xsel or xclip

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, copy-paste, virtualbox

I am able to copy/paste from my guest (Ubuntu 10.10) into my host (OS X 10.6) using the standard shft-ctrl-c to copy anything highlighted on the screen.  This works fine.

Also I can `cat something.txt | xsel` or `cat something.txt | xclip` and paste within Ubuntu fine.  That works too.

What does not work: `cat something.txt | xsel`, then paste it in my host OS X.

Does anyone know why the "normal" clipboard copy works across guest/host OS's, but the command-line xsel and xclip copy techniques only work locally, not across OS's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the relevant options?

```
--primary   (-p)
--secondary (-s) 
--clipboard (-b)
```

If that doesn't help it sounds like an oversight on the part of the implementors of the Virtual Machine Additions for Linux guests. You might file a bug report at

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

You might try your luck with [`xclip`](http://elcasey.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/xclip-use-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line) instead

Comment: Yep I tried all the flags, and xclip too.  I'll fill out a bug report as you suggested.  Thanks for the link.